# Group by if two column in different row has the same value?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to groupby the column1 then count it. Now if the column1 and column2 has same value in other row then it will count only as one

**example table**

```
column1  column2
2        4
1        1
1        1
3        4
2        4
3        1
1        3
```

**example output**

```
column1  column2  count
2        4        1
1        3        2
3        4        2
```

As you can see the `2` in column1 is only counted as 1 because the column2 is also same in other row.

How can I do that in mysql or eloquent query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - it'll work in mysql

```
select column1,max(column2),count(distinct column2)
from tablename
group by column1
```

Comment: If I remove max nothing will change right? the max is only for getting the largest number? Thanks btw its working

Answer (score 1):

You can try the query:

```
select t.column1, t.column2, count(*) as count from (
  select column1, column2 from mytables group by column1, column2
  order by column2 desc
) as t
group by t.column1
```

then its result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

seems you need the count for distinct column1, max(column2)

```
select column1, max(column2), count(*) 
from (
  select distinct column1, column2 
  from my_table  
) t  
group by  column1
```